# I am not able to push my code on git?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

when i fire this command is show's error like below.

```
  git push origin master
```

shows an error

```
 Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
 Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
 Could not resolve proxy: proxy
 Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'git@github.com:xyz/abc.git': Could not resolve proxy: proxy
```

Comment: Have you try this `git clone git@github.com:xyz/abc.git`

Comment: Why does the error message mention both bitbucket.org and github.com?

Comment: actually i used bitbucket.org so.

Comment: Could you show the result of `git remote show origin`?

Comment: You've got problem with network or proxy configuration. See: `couldn't fiind host`, and `Could not resolve proxy`.  In my opinion you have either system or git proxy address set incorrectly (to `proxy`  which is incorect net address). Also take a look into `.netrc` file which also contains some errors.

Comment: what `git config core.gitproxy` prints?